# UICollectionView tapped animation like iPhone photos app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to replicate the exact same didSelect animation / segue when you tap a photo in the iPhone's photo app *(or in almost every so other app)* where the photo enlarges from the cell itself into a modal view controller, and minimizes to wherever it belongs to in the grid when dismissed.

I tried googling but couldn't find any articles about this.

Comment: [This may help you](https://github.com/mariohahn/MHVideoPhotoGallery). It has many functional examples. In order to make this work you'll need to use the transitioning and animating classes.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481004/how-to-animate-a-uiimageview-to-display-fullscreen-by-tapping-on-it) may answer your question

Answer (score 7):

There are many public repos on git that could probably do what you want. Some stuff I've found:
https://github.com/mariohahn/MHVideoPhotoGallery
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Those may be overly complicated. Another option is creating a UIImageView at the same place as the cell and then animating it to fill the screen. This code assumes the collectionView has an origin at (0,0), if not then simply add the collectionView's offset when calculating the initial frame.

```
collectionView.scrollEnabled = false; // disable scrolling so view won't move
CGPoint innerOffset = collectionView.contentOffset; // offset of content view due to scrolling
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0] ];
CGRect cellRect = attributes.frame; // frame of cell in contentView

UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x - innerOffset.x, cellRect.origin.y - innerOffset.y, cellRect.size.width, cellRect.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:v]; // or add to whatever view you want
v.image = image; // set your image
v.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; // don't get stupid scaling
// animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [v setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; // assume filling the whole screen
}];
```

It's not the nice popping animation but it should still look ok.

Comment: did you mean `cellRect.origin.x - innerOffset.x` instead of `cellRect.origin.x + innerOffset.x`? (the same with y).