# FullScreen image through tap on TableCell's image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, fullscreen

I'm trying to show a fullscreen picture from a smaller one included in a custom UITableViewCell. My code is highly linked to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481004/how-to-animate-a-uiimageview-to-display-fullscreen-by-tapping-on-it)

By the way, in this example, the frame : `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`is not the good one for me. It's the an `UIScrollView`'s bounds that I've got. I this to add the main screen through a variable inside the cell directly when each cell is created. So I've customized the previous example like this :

```
//viewDidLoad
self.globalView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

//cellForRowAtIndexPath
[cell setFullScreenView:self.globalView];

//fullScreenMethod
if (!isFullScreen) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        //save previous frame
        prevFrame = imageView.frame;
        [imageView setFrame:self.fullScreenView.frame];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        isFullScreen = YES;
    }];
    return;
}
```

My problem is that the `imageView`'s new frame is not a full screen but still the `UIScrollView`'s one.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Couldn't get you exactly...

Comment: can you provide screenshot..?

Comment: when you touch the image in cell do you want any kind of animation or want to show the image in full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach is create one temporary `UIImageView` and Show it in full screen,
For animation simply add the temporary `UIImageView` to location where the image view exists and animate it to full-screen and do revers for normal

Add tap gesture to `UIImageView` and add this `bannerTapped` as selector

```
     //This will create a temporary imaget view and animate it to fullscreen
            - (void)bannerTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
                NSLog(@"%@", [gestureRecognizer view]);
                //create new image
                temptumb=(UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;

                //fullview is gloabal, So we can acess any time to remove it
                fullview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
                  [fullview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                [fullview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bckgrd.png"]]];
                fullview.image = [(UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view image];
                    CGRect point=[self.view convertRect:gestureRecognizer.view.bounds fromView:gestureRecognizer.view];
                [fullview setFrame:point];

                [self.view addSubview:fullview];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                 animations:^{
                                     [fullview setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                   0,
                                                                   self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                                   self.view.bounds.size.height)];
                                 }];
                UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fullimagetapped:)];
                singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
                [fullview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
                [fullview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            }

        //This will remove the full screen and back to original location.

            - (void)fullimagetapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

                CGRect point=[self.view convertRect:temptumb.bounds fromView:temptumb];

                gestureRecognizer.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                 animations:^{
                                     [(UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view setFrame:point];
                                 }];
                [self performSelector:@selector(animationDone:) withObject:[gestureRecognizer view] afterDelay:0.4];

            }

//Remove view after animation of remove
            -(void)animationDone:(UIView  *)view
            {
                //view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                [fullview removeFromSuperview];
                fullview=nil;
            }
```

Comment: This method seems exactly what I wanted to do. By the way, I have few more questions. Where am I suppose to declare the  `fullview` global variable ? Cannot I just pass the fullView directly as parameters of my customized cell as I tried ?

Comment: just declare it as field in Interface **@Interface Name{ UIImageView *fullView }** in .m file

Comment: Ok ! It works ! Thank you ! But I have a little last problem but I can try to fix it alone. This image to show in full screen is not the same that this I touch. Each picture has different urls (on for each size). All these pictures are save on an Array. I don't have any idea of how to do that yet. Thank you again for your help !

Comment: Last question if I may. I found a way to solve the selected picture problem I had. By the way. The fullScreen is taking the whole place (without deformation it's perfect) but on the cell only. It's a fullCell and not a fullScreen if you seen what I mean. When I try to to set the frame of the UIView with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` it's almost perfect but this image goes out of the cell so it's not anymore visible. In my mind, this is because the `@fullScreen` is on the `cell.m`. It should be on my main controller directly isn't it ?

Comment: fullScreen should be in mainController not in your Custom Cell Class, Its just temporary reference to remove the full-screen when user tap gain.

Comment: That's what I thought. By the way, this effect is not that bad finally. I will maybe keep it like that ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It can't take a full screen frame because its parent view is the scrollView.  Either show view modally or somehow move imageView directly under view controller's main view.