# UitableView image to fullscreen

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I am writing a program in Xcode in which i work with a tableview. In this tableview in every cell there is a small image. Now i would like this image to become full screen when the user taps it. I know this question was already asked several times but either the answer was in objective c (I'm writing in Swift) or when explain in Swift it swift. If someone could help me and give me a other solution or translate the working answers to Swift I'd be so so grateful. That would be awesome.

Thanks a lot.

Here are the links to the answers which seem to work (regarding the number of upvotes or checks ):

[Expand UIImageView to full screen from within UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242805/expand-uiimageview-to-full-screen-from-within-uitableviewcell)

[FullScreen image through tap on TableCell's image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053694/fullscreen-image-through-tap-on-tablecells-image)

Comment: Simply use presentviewcontroller and then design screen ( in which set imageview in full screen) , present it on Image Tap

Answer (score -1):

Make a new View in your storyboard. Make a segue from the cell to the new view then in the viewcontroller overwrite the prepareForSegue method. you have to pass the image to the new view.

This link could help: http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

Comment: I used the code but data was not transferred. Are you sure this work also with a table view?

Comment: Don't you know a method without introducing a new controller?

Comment: but you want to show the picture fullscreen after tapping the cell correct? In order to show the picture you need to have another controller in which you want to show this picture.

Comment: Yes but the problem is the following. I have tried every suggested solution i found using a new view controller and none of them worked. So I though that maybe there is also a method without it. Maybe some kind of temporar animation e.g.