# How to show full image when user taps on image view in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple images in detail view controller. Now, I want that If user touches any of them then it will push to another view controller and shows image in full size.

Please help me.

**Note : I am not asking about table view controller or collection view controller, I am asking about just simple view controller.**

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12481177/3976183. May Help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put UIButton behind UIImageview and write code on action of button, So when you click on UIImage, UIButton will pressed and will show image in full size.

Answer (score 4):

*Instead of UIImageView use UIButton and in action of UIButton, write code to show image in full screen*

***OR***

*Add tap gesture on UIImageView and in action of tap gesture, write code to show full screen image*

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // this is very very important else it wont work
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneTouch=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(OneTouchHandeler)];
[oneTouch setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];    
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:oneTouch];

-(void)OneTouchHandeler {
    // your code here to show image full screen
}
```

Comment: How to set movie player play in custom cell when user click on button. I had added button in custom cell, but how to manage it that when user click on image in cell then image will set hidden and video play in the place of image view. If you know please help me.
@Note I want to play video in custom cell

Answer (score 1):

You could import an open-sourced project, such as the [AKImageViewer](https://github.com/aleckretch/AKImageViewer), to handle displaying images full-sized in a clean way (swipe gestures, double tap handling, and smooth transitions all similar to viewing an image full sized in the Twitter or GroupMe apps).